# Как на сервере получить список для последующей обработки?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Есть следующие классы

```
public class OrderItemAddModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int DetailId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ToolSelectionListModel> ListOfOrderItems { get; set; }
    }

public class ToolSelectionListModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string OrderCode { get; set; }
        public int AmountRequired { get; set; }
    }
```

Представление

```
@model Web.Models.Orders.OrderItemAddModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrderItem", "Order", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Products, string.Empty, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control",
            data_url = @Url.Action("GetDetailsByProductId", "Order")})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DetailId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DetailId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Details, string.Empty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DetailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <hr />
    @Html.Partial("_ToolSelectionList",Model.ToolList)
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Хочу сделать представление следующего вида: в представлении пользователь выбирает необходимые ему позиции (из справочника), указывает необходимое количество, после подтверждения выбранные позиции должны добавиться в базу. У меня есть следующий метод:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddOrderItem(OrderItemAddModel model, string returnUrl)
{

}
```

Как в него получить список позиций для последующей обработки: добавления необходимых позиций в БД.

**Частичное представление для отображения списка инструмента:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Tools.ToolSelectionListModel>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Selected)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderCode)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AmountRequired)</th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Selected)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderCode)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.AmountRequired)</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получить данные из модели в контроллере проще простого:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddOrderItem(OrderItemAddModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   int Id = model.ProductId;
   int DetailId = model.DetailId;

   return View("Index");
}
```

источник : [Getting Data From View to Controller in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639709/Getting-Data-From-View-to-Controller-in-MVC)

Список выбранных опций можно хранить в сессиях, напрмер вот так:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrderItem(OrderItemAddModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        List<ToolSelectionListModel> list;
        if (Session["myData"] == null)
            list = new List<ToolSelectionListModel>();
        else 
            list = (List<ToolSelectionListModel>)Session["myData"];

        var item = new ToolSelectionListModel() { Id = model.Id,   Selected = true, OrderCode="myCode"};
        list.Add(item);
        Session["myData"] = list;

        return View("Index");//здесь имя View которое мы хотим увидеть после выполнения кода
    }
```

Comment: а список ListOfOrderItems = null. а мне необходимо получить его для последующей обработки

Comment: А что в нем должно быть?

Comment: в нем должен быть список с внесенными изменениями. т.е. я хочу форму в которой пользователь меняет "данные"(отмечает необходимые позиции, указывает количество) и нажимает кнопку. после чего мне хотелось бы получить данный список и обработать его дальше

Comment: Отредактировал. Предлагаю хранить выбранные значения в переменнной Session. Хотя,  думаю можно и в модели хранить.

Comment: Если вы хотели как-то хранить выбранные данные с помощью @Html.Partial("_ToolSelectionList",Model.ToolList), то давайте тогда код от вашего view _ToolSelectionList.cshtml

Comment: обновил. как сделать иную форму для отображения списка инструмента пока не придумал.получилось как то так

Comment: Ну как я говорил проще всего хранить в сессии. Если нет, то вы просто так не получите данные из Partial View  в вашем контроллере. Для этого нужно будет реализовать Model Binder. Пример как есть тут : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder